# Amchart annotations . Returning back to normal mode from annotations mode

Tags: annotations, amcharts

I am using external buttons for am charts export. when i enter into annotations mode and do export, the chart gets exported with annotations. But when the chart gets reloaded , the annotations mode does not revert back.

Could somebody let me know how to go back from annotations to normal mode.

```
 if (chart.export.drawing.buffer.enabled === true) {
                 // Exporting the annotated chart with out " 
                 //chart.export.capture"
                chart.export.toPNG({}, function (data) {
                    chartimage.postImageData(data, chart_image_name)
                });
            } else {

                chart.export.capture({
                    // action: "draw"

                }, function () {
                    this.toPNG({

                    }, function (data) {
                        images.push({
                            "image": data,
                            "fit": [523.28, 769.89]
                        });
                        pending--;
                        if (pending === 0) {
                            chart.export.toPNG({
                                content: images
                            }, function (data) {
                                chartimage.postImageData(data, chart_image_name)
                            });
                        }
                    });
                });
            }

        }
```

Comment: Take a look here: https://www.amcharts.com/kbase/using-export-api-functions-dynamically-save-load-chart-annotations/

Comment: Thanks – Martynasma. However this link doesn't say how to revert back to normal mode. I need something like chart.export.drawing.buffer.enabled =false. To be more specific , i need to trigger annotations cancel option manually. Any ideas?

Comment: Just posted another example: https://www.amcharts.com/kbase/toggling-export-annotation-mode/ Will post as SO answer for other people to see.

Answer (score 2):

To exit from Annotation mode, simply use Export plugin's internal API method `done()`:

```
chart["export"].drawing.handler.done();
```

BTW, `export` keyword is reserved and will result in errors on some browsers. It's better to access Export instance via named key: `chart["export"].toPNG()` versus `chart.export.toPNG()`.

Answer (score 0):

Please find the workaround below..

First capture the events for set and cancel annotations using menu reviewer

```
menuReviver: function (item, li) {
    if (item.format === "XLSX" || item.format === "JSON") {
    li.style.display = "none";
    }

    $(li).click(function () {
    if (item.action == "draw") {
        $("#chart_annotations").val(1);
    }
    if (item.action == "cancel") {
        $("#chart_annotations").val(0);
    }

    });

    return li;
}
```

Now while exporting the chart image use $("#chart_annotations").val() value as a 
flag whether to export annotated chart or a normal chart. Please find the code below...

```
if (window.fabric) {
    if ($("#chart_annotations").val() == 1) {
        chart.export.toPNG({}, function (data) {
        chartimage.postImageData(data, chart_image_name)
        });
    } else {

        chart.export.capture({
        //action: "change"

        }, function () {
        this.toPNG({

        }, function (data) {
            images.push({
            "image": data,
            "fit": [523.28, 769.89]
            });
            pending--;
            if (pending === 0) {
            chart.export.toPNG({
                content: images
            }, function (data) {
                 //post the image data using ajax
                chartimage.postImageData(data, chart_image_name)
            });
            }
        });
        });
    }
```